# how to shift flex 3 project into flex4/flash 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

i have a project which already make in flex 3.Now i want to shift it in flash4/flex4 .
Anyone how tell me how i can shift it into flash4/flex4.And can use the new features in my project.
kind regards.....

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc86a71867f5b4fa8351045f125dffc40d0-7fff.html
Anyone who want this study this article.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/FeaturesAndMigration/flex_4_features.pdf